# RApache does not find correct paths to packages

Tags: r, configuration, rapache

I am trying to configure Apache on my Linux system, but it does not find the correct paths to R packages (and so it does not find the `brew` package).

I install R packages in `~/R/libs` and, when running `.libPaths()` from an R session I get:

```
[1] "/home/nico/R/libs"    "/usr/lib/R/library"   "/usr/share/R/library"
```

However, if I configure RApache to show me `RApacheInfo()` by using

```
<Location /RApacheInfo>
SetHandler r-info
</Location>
```

in .libPaths RApache only reports

```
/usr/lib/R/library
/usr/share/R/library
```

How do I tell RApache to go looking in `~/R/libs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [RApache Configuration Documentation](http://rapache.net/manual.html#Configuring_rapache) you could try the 
`REvalOnStartup` directive to set `.libPaths()` directly.

Comment: Good idea, did not think about it, I'll let you know if it works. Two extra questions: 1. do you know if the discrepancy is normal or is RApache supposed to see also my custom library path? 2. have you specifically seen this pointed out in the docs? I can't seem to find it any mention of libpaths in the docs.

Comment: If you have a custom path, you have to tell R somewhere and somehow about it. Remember that your user id is typically not the one RApache runs at---so one is better of with $R_HOME/etc/Rprofile.site et al rather than $HOME/.Rprofile.  And I put local packages etc into /usr/local/R/site-library rather than in my $HOME for the same reason.

Comment: right... now it makes sense, and it works! I like to put packages in home so that I don't have to reinstall them when I update the system.

Comment: Well I still feel my approach is preferable: /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ is visible to all users on the system, and not affected by R upgrades via the package manager (as I rely on .deb packages, given that I am maintainer of those for Debian).